# Generate files with laravel command

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan

I need to create a number of files in a specific format. So I planned to create a generate command by extending `GeneratorCommand`. I want to create view files and view-config files in application root directory.

The problem is, I did not find any official doc to do so. There are some article in the web, which suggests to use `getDefaultNamespace` method to set the path like the following. I was following the steps suggested at https://laravelpackage.com/06-artisan-commands.html#creating-a-generator-command. But I want to create files in root dir not into app dir. When i remove the `$rootNamespace` form the method it does not create files.

```
protected function getDefaultNamespace($rootNamespace)
{
    return $rootNamespace.'\Actions';
}
```

how can i create a command to generate files in specific directories in the application?

Comment: Does it work now?

Comment: @GordonFreeman not successful yet, checking the package you referred.

Answer (score 1):

[The class `GeneratorCommand` has a protected method `rootNamespace`](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Console/GeneratorCommand.html#method_rootNamespace). If I understand correctly, it returns the root ouf your application.

So you should be able to override the method `getNamespace` like so:

```php
/**
 * Get the full namespace for a given class, without the class name.
 *
 * @param  string  $name
 * @return string
 */
protected function getNamespace($name)
{
    $rootNamespace = trim($this->rootNamespace(), '\\');
    return $this->getDefaultNamespace($rootNamespace);
}
```

NOTE
You can see [a working example](https://github.com/Artem-Schander/L5Modular/blob/master/src/Console/SeederMakeCommand.php) in one of my open source projects.